# PowerShell to add items to a form library

Tags: powershell, forms-library

I am able to easily add items to a list using powershell. I have found that this does not work so easily when dealing with a FORM LIBRARY.

I am using something like this below which works like a peach for a list:

```
$TargetList = $web.Lists[$TargetListNam]
$TargetItem = $TargetList.items.add()   
$TargetItem["Facility_Name"] = $SourceItem["FacilityName"]
$TargetItem.Update()
```

However,using this same code with a FORM Library does not seem to work.

Has anyone done anything like this with a form library before?

A few notes:

- While the Form Library does hold the .xml content for the InfoPath form, all of that is derived from fields in the list.
- Using a Workflow I can create a new List Item in the Library easily enough, so I am assuming this is something easy I am missing.

**Assumptions:**

Form Library Name: Worklist

**Goal**

I have a list that is currently looping through a BDC Model an inserting or updating records that are then used by end-users.

I need to change that list to a FORM Library due to attachment control reasons and figured I could just point the code to the new Worklist without issue....alas I can't.

I have though about trying something like this, that works with a regular document library:

```
$spWeb = Get-SPWeb -Identity http://SPServer 
$spFolder = $spWeb.GetFolder("My Documents")
$spFileCollection = $spFolder.Files
$file = Get-ChildItem C:\Documents\MyDoc.docx
$spFileCollection.Add("My Documents/MyDoc.docx",$file.OpenRead(),$false`)
```

The issue is I have no documents to add, these are just data point derived from a BDC list.

Comment: I know this is not directly related to your question, but when you add a new item through server-side code, you should call `$TargetList.AddItem()`, instead of `$TargetList.Items.Add()`.  Reason being, in the server API, any type you access the `Items` property, even to call the `Add()` method, the API is loading the entire `Items` collection from the list, which could not only be slow in a large list, but could break completely if the List View Threshold is exceeded.  Calling `AddItem` directly on the SPList avoids this unnecessary load.

Answer (score 1):

A Form Library is a specialized type of Document Library.  Just like the Document Library, you cannot just call `items.add()` or `list.addItem()`, because you have to upload a file into the library before you have a listItem you can add metadata to.

To upload a file, you would first need to have an IO Stream of some sort, either a FileStream if you are reading a file from disk, or a MemoryStream if you are constructing a file from scratch in code.  Then you need to grab a reference to the library's root folder `$folder = $TargetList.RootFolder`, and call `$folder.Files.Add(NewFileNameToBeUsedInLibrary, FileStream)`.

Once the File is added to the library, now you can get that file's Item and updated metadata.

One big caveat here, if this is a Form Library, it is expecting XML files that are instances of a Form being completed.  Unlike a "regular" document library, there could be all sorts of weird behavior if you are uploading some filetype that is not expected in a Form Library.

Answer (score 0):

Folks, the answer to this can be broken down into 2 solutions.

I will go through each and will update this with code as I finalize the work.

**Solution 1: (Easy but cheesy)**

Use a worklfow with SPD. Which, on the surface sounds easy but requires some tweaking.

Essentially once your form has been completed you will want to submit a blank version of the document. This will result in the XML file being generated. Using either the UI or SPD simply open the file and you have the XML that generates the forms.

With this information you can adjust the XML as needed but you will want to save it as Template.XML. You will then want to go to your FORM Library and turn off the "Allow management of content types". This is automatically enabled for FORM Libraries.

Once you have that off , using SPD upload the Template XML to the Library in the FORMS directory. DO NOT REMOVE THE XSN file.

In the UI set the Document Template to the XML file you uploaded.

After this has been completed SPD Workflows can be used to create items in a FORM LIBRARY using the form and it will save properly. If you are having to loop through a BDC or something you will be better off using Workflow 2013 so be sure that is configured .

**Solution 2: (Powershell)**

Once you know you have to save the file using the XML format it is easy enough to do a stream output and create the files on the fly using a PowerShell script.

I will be posting code on how this is accomplished.